# Synchronization & Object locks in multi threading in JAVA

Tags: java, synchronization, locks

Assume that one thread is running a synchronized method so got a lock on the object's instance. Also assume that the thread goes to runnable state from running state. Then what happens to that object lock. Is it released before the thread goes to runnable state?. Please help me with a correct answer :).

Thanks in advance,
Mahendra Reddy.

Comment: I've confused with your thread states. According to [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) there is no "Running" state.

Answer (score 1):

The lock is not released unless it is WAITING. (i.e. called wait()) or it has exited the last synchronized block for that lock.

The thread is in the RUNNABLE whether the OS has scheduled the thread to be running or not.